# findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode with React.createRef()

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, components

I'm using a functional component in react to launch a popup form. I want to grab the values in the form on submission and was using the `variable = React.createRef()` and then a `ref={variable}` in the input field to retrieve them but I keep getting

```
Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in Strictmode
```

error in the console. Is there a better way to do this?

```
Const AddProduct = (section) => {
 const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
 const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
 const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

 let itemName = React.createRef();

 const createProduct = () => {
    
   console.log(itemName.current.value);
   handleClose();
 };

 return (
   <>
     <a href="#" className="nav-link" onClick={handleShow}>
       Add Product
     </a>

     <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
       <Modal.Header>
         <Modal.Title>Create Item</Modal.Title>
       </Modal.Header>
       <Modal.Body>
         <Form.Group controlId="itemName">
           <Form.Label>Item Name</Form.Label>
           <Form.Control type="text" name="name" ref={itemName} />   
</Form.Group>
       </Modal.Body>
       <Modal.Footer>
         <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
           Close
         </Button>
         <Button variant="primary" onClick={createProduct}>
           Create
         </Button>
       </Modal.Footer>
     </Modal>
   </>
 );
};
```

Comment: did you try using useRef hooks?

Comment: unforutntealy same Warning message with  let itemName =useRef("");